# Entropy per site of quantum spin chain

Tags: linear-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, asymptotics, statistical-physics

It’s fork lore that von Neumann entropy (and free energy) grows linearly with respect to the size of a quantum system. Is there a rigorous demonstration in the toy model of a quantum spin chain with (translation invariant) nearest neighborhood interaction (in the absence of integrability)? Can we determine the entropy (or free energy) per site in terms of the local interaction?

Comment: It's not just "fork lore", it's theorems.  See e.g. Ruelle, "Statistical Mechanics", chapters 2 (for the free energy) and 7 (for the entropy).

Comment: @RobertIsrael This completely solved my question, thank you very much! I appreciate your kind help.